# Editing the Help Center

Tags: discussion, faq-content, help-center

It looks like our [FAQ link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq) now redirects to a help center. I don't think it has the same information as it used to (it would seem, not 100% positive).

This is apparently universally rolled-out across all SE sites according to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center).

Personally I find it much more difficult to find what I'm looking for in there, and I was wondering what, if anything, we have for options in customizing it?

Could a mod chime in and maybe get a discussion started on how we can improve it?

Comment: New help center is crap!  The previous FAQ was set up in a nice, easy to read and understand sequential order.  there were resources in certain questions that would be of immediate use to newcommers, and overall it presented a better sense of the members of this site knowing what we're doing.

Comment: @acolyte - The answer is to point new users to the [about] page. You can put `[about]` directly in comments using that markup to quickly insert the link. I see the help center as something they'd go to after reading the about page and spending some time on the site. I agree it does look a little overwhelming, but when we leave comments we should pick the part that's most helpful for that user's circumstances. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @jmort253 that's just it, i don't think any of it is all that useful.  They've combined the tour function which already existed, with the FAQ.  The FAQ in its previous iteration was far more effective and easy to read, it was nicely organized with a fast to navigate list of topics.  One half of the screen was information, one half was topics.  I'm picking the most helpful parts about the new page, nothing.  I don't think there are any benefits to this change.

Answer (score 4):

I've just taken the time to dig through it a bit, and I agree it's more complicated. I'm unsure of whether the added complexity makes it worse, or if the aggregation and organization of the information will make it easier for new users.

As far as editing, the "take the tour" button goes to the old /about page, and it seems mods are able to do some minor editing there (site intro, example question, ask about/don't ask about). Aside from that, the only section we can edit is the [on- and off-topic page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic).

It looks like any other changes will need to be done by the Stack Exchange team (and may be network-wide rather than site-specific, but I'm unsure that's the case).

Comment: *Insert picture of me looking like the home alone kid here*